# background music should stop on click wordpress website

Tags: jquery, wordpress, onclick

I am working on this website https://limbicmusic.com.br/. I want to stop the background music when we click on links at the bottom of the page. Iam trying this jQuery code.  But this code only stops toggle button animation not music on click. Kindly guide.

```js
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$(".mfp-video").click(function(){

$(".music_toggle").removeClass("on");
 
});

})
```

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score 0):

You are making a change to the sound button, not the actual video. You'll need to mute the video explicitly like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".mfp-video").click(function() {
        $(".music_toggle").removeClass("on");
        $('body').find('video').prop('muted', true);
    });

})
```

Comment: which video?? I just want to mute the background music not any video.

Comment: Music is triggered by video and you need to mute the video to stop the music.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the **pause()** function and set the **currentTime** variable value to 0.

Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var myVideo = document.getElementById('video_id'); //ID of <video> tag
    $(".mfp-video").click(function() {
        $(".music_toggle").removeClass("on");
        myVideo.pause();
        myVideo.currentTime = 0;
    });
})
```

Comment: what is myvideo??

Comment: myVideo is a variable holding the object of `<video>` tag like this `<video id="video_id">`